# FAST Search 2010 : Spell Suggestion

Tags: 2010, fast-search

My content has the word `coverdell` in several places. And my users wants FAST to suggest for `coverdell` when they type `coverdale` which produces no results.

I understand FAST is not suggesting `coverdell` in place of `coverdale` because FAST thinks `coverdale` is a valid dictionary word. Is there any way I can tweak the system so that users see `coverdell` as suggestion when they type `coverdale`?

Answer (score 1):

You can manually add search suggestions which will appear below the searchbox as you type (if enabled). See this post for details: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shad_phillips/archive/2010/06/09/adding-query-suggestions-to-fast-2010-for-sharepoint-2010.aspx

Perhaps a better approach is to add a synonym: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg604770(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: Thanks. Suggestion does not work because user may still type the word ignoring suggestions. Synonym sounds like a workable solution which we are using currently. But I am not happy with it because they are NOT true synonyms. My up vote for the answer!

Comment: It's correct it's not a true synonym per the dictionary definition. But per search definition, this is what you typically use synonyms for. People misspell a lot of terms, and as a search admin you have to add synonyms to make sure they get what they want. So you are doing it the correct way imo :)

Answer (score 0):

If synonyms and suggestions are off, your options are limited to other non SharePoint solutions. Maybe a little jQuery would do the trick?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#searchFieldID').text(function(i, oldText) {
        return oldText === 'coverdale' ? 'coverdell' : oldText;
    });
});
```